# How to change the date language in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, date-formatting, php-carbon

I want to change the language of the date i get in my view from english to french

```
{{ strftime("%d %B %Y, %H:%M", strtotime($article->created_at)) }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `Carbon` locale first, then access

```
Carbon::setLocale('fr');
$date_to_show_in_view = $article->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

For your second query(to get `15 Mars 2018`), use this-

```
<?php
   setlocale(LC_TIME, 'French');
   echo $base_weight_category->created_at->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');
?>
```

Comment: can i apply this directly in the view ?

Comment: yes, you can, like this `<?php
                                            \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('fr');
                                            echo $date_to_show_in_view = $base_weight_category->created_at->diffForHumans();
                                            ?>`

Comment: it worked but i don't want it with the diffforHumans()  result i want for example like this (15 Mars 2018)

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya then use format method `$base_weight_category->created_at->format('d M Y')`

Comment: i wrote this <?php \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('fr'); echo $last_writing->created_at->format('d F Y'); ?> but i still get it displayed in english is it because i don't have french language in my laravel project ?

Comment: the result "il y a 1 jour" but i want it like this "15 Mars 2018"

Comment: thank you very much especially for your patience with me :D

Comment: I have a little problem with months like (Février, Août, Décembre ) i get them displayed for example like this :f�vrier (i'm working on windows 10 )

Comment: may be its something about html language support type, let me check

Comment: i have this in the top of my view <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: this should have worked with `utf-8`, are you using french for localization??

Comment: how can i know that because i'm working on a project that i didn't start from the beginning

Comment: it would be better  if you discuss with your colleagues or senior, its really hard to understand this way, this might be a silly matter which we are not understanding

Comment: Well i'm gonna try to find a solution hope this problem doesn't persist

Comment: i found a solution have this this line written in my route : setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); and in the view:{{ strftime("%d %B %Y, %H:%M", strtotime($invoice->invoice_date)) }}

Comment: @Sohel0415, hi dude, I am just beginner in Laravel and I really need your help. Look, I used your updated code like this: <small> {{setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Russian'),
         $personal->created_at->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y') }}</small> instead of French I used Russian but in the view it shows:Russian_Russia1252. Did I do everything properly. I hope for your attention :)

Comment: @Mirich Use `<?php ?>` tag instead of `{{}}`, then let me know what happens.

Comment: @Sohel0415, I have used the code like this:<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Russian');
         $personal->created_at->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y'); ?> and got empty result, I mean, there is nothing rendered in the view

Comment: @Mirich you missed the echo part

Comment: @Sohel0415, again me ok I have added echo and got this result 10 �������� 2018. Have you ever encountered with such issue?

Comment: @Mirich use `UTF-8`   as charset, this might be language support issue

Comment: @Sohel0415, yes I am certainly using UTF-8 but all the same:(. I dunno why

Comment: @Mirich seems everything ok,,it should work with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @Sohel0415, sorry dude I found out that database collation has to be the same as UTF-8 right? That is, utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Is this correct?

Answer (score 10):

we can use another method with translatedFormat

```
    Carbon::setLocale('fr');
echo $base_weight_category->created_at->translatedFormat('l jS F Y');
```

we can see result  jeudi 2 avril 2020

Comment: With translatedFormat(), the Carbon::setLocale(…) line is not necessary if Laravel's language is well defined in config/app.php ( ex : 'locale' => 'fr')

Comment: i use it to explain my example in french

Answer (score 1):

i always use attribute in the model with this function

```
public function getReservationDateFormatAttribute() {
    return Carbon::parse($this->reservation_date)->locale(app()->getLocale())->translatedFormat('d F Y');
}
```

between the get & Attribute i pass the name or title of the attribute that i will call in my example will call it this way

```
$model_name->reservation_date_format;
```

and more specific answer for the question is next code

```
Carbon::parse($this->reservation_date)->locale(app()->getLocale())->translatedFormat('d F Y');
```

after we parse the the value you pass, just set the locale to whatever you want in my example i use the app locale because the project is multi language
after the locale use the fromat you prefer for your application.
hope the answer help