# Convert date format in French

Tags: laravel, date, format

Good morning EveryBody

Is it possible to convert this in date french format

```
{{ $data->updated_at }}
```

For exemple 20 Avril 2021.
Thanks

Comment: Laravel uses Carbon to deal with dates, take a look at their localization doc: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
{{
    \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('fr');
    echo $data->updated_at->translatedFormat('%d %B %Y');                                           
}}
```

this is what you're looking for [How to change the date language in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298454/how-to-change-the-date-language-in-laravel)

Comment: Thanks you my Dear.  I use your link to find the good solution. It's working with this: <?php
   setlocale(LC_TIME, 'French');
   echo $data->updated_at->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');
?>